# TypeError object is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, export

I'm developing an application in node.js with MongoDB
I have to files:
product.js and displaycost.js

this is product .js:

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Category = require('./category');

var productSchema = {
name:{type: String, require: true},
//Pictures mus start with "http://"
pictures:[{type:String, match: /^http:\/\//i}],
price:{
amount:{type: Number, required: true},
//ONly 3 supported currencies for now
currency:{
type: String,
enum:['USD','EUR','GBP'],
required: true
}
},
category: Category.categorySchema
};
var schema = new mongoose.Schema(productSchema);

var currencySymbols ={
'USD': '$',
'EUR':'€',
'GBP':'£'
};

/*
* 
*/
schema.virtual('displayPrice').get(function(){
return currencySymbols[this.price.currency] +
'' + this.price.amount;
});

schema.set('toObject', {virtuals:true});
schema.set('toJSON', {virtuals:true});

module.exports = schema;
```

What I need is create a record with "productSchema"
I tried with this:

```
var Product  = require('./product.js');

var p = new Product({
name: 'test',
price:{
amount : 5,
currency: 'USD'
},
category: {
name: 'test'
}
});

console.log(p.displayPrice); // "$5"

p.price.amount = 20;
console.log(p.displayPrice); //" $20"

//{... "displayPrice: "$20",...}
console.log(JSON.stringify(p));

var obj = p.toObject();
```

But when I run the displaycost.js throw me an error at the word "new"
and writes "TypeError: object is not a function"

I don't know why is happening that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missing export mongoose model with model name.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    Category = require('./category');

var productSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, require: true},
    pictures: [{type: String, match: /^http:\/\//i}],
    price: {
        amount: {type: Number, required: true},
        currency: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['USD', 'EUR', 'GBP'],
            required: true
        }
    },
    category: Category
});

var currencySymbols = {
    'USD': '$',
    'EUR': '€',
    'GBP': '£'
};

productSchema.virtual('displayPrice').get(function () {
    return currencySymbols[this.price.currency] +
        '' + this.price.amount;
});

productSchema.set('toObject', {virtuals: true});
productSchema.set('toJSON', {virtuals: true});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works.  I suffered a headache because of that.

Answer (score 0):

"new" can only be called on a function. not an object.

In program.js you are creating a new instance of the mongoose schema.

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema(productSchema);

... more code ...

return schema;
```

In your other js file you require product. At this point in time product.js has returned an object to you. A new mongoose schema. It is an object which you are refering to as Product.

You then try to create a new instance of it by calling new on the product OBJECT. New cannot be called on an object literal. It can only be called on a function.

I don't believe you need to make a new instance of schema within product.js, just return the function that creates the schema. Then call new on it when you require it like you are in your second file.